# iPhone SDK UIProgressView tint color and App Store Rejection

Tags: iphone

I've written an iPhone application that is just about ready to be submitted to the Apple Store. My app uses a UIProgressView to indicate the progress of a download. I noticed that the only customization is the aqua blue or default style. I found some code and info on the web that lets me set the tint color of a sub-classed UIProgressBar.

Will sub classing this Apple control and adding functionality to it for setting the tint color get my app rejected? Thanks for your replies in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Extending a built-in class by subclassing it is a normal and expected part of objected-oriented development.  As long as your custom class does not use any private properties or methods you shouldn't run into any problems.  In particular, if what the code you found does is override `UIProgressView`'s `drawRect:` method, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The review of your app is not a code-review, they just start your app a few times & determine if the interface adheres to the UI guidelines, if it does not crash, does not contain offensive content, ...

They have no way of knowing you subclassed their control, you could have written a control from scratch to mimic the stock progress bar and wouldn't have any clue. Your sending the compiled app to them and not your sourcecode.

A reason for rejecting your app would rather be, if you're using a progress bar and using it for something completely different than indicating that your app is busy doing something.

Comment: I don't agree. I've seen rejection reports where they DO mention specific classes that have code that Apple "doesn't like".

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean UIProgressView?  If so use:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *progressTintColor
```

as in:

```
self.progressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```